# Filter Directory using Regex and output filtered files to another directory

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, glob, os.path

I am simply trying to create a python 3 program that runs through all .sql files in a specific directory and then apply my regex that adds ; after a certain instance and write the changes made to the file to a separate directory with their respective file names as the same.

So, if I had file1.sql and file2.sql in "/home/files" directory, after I run the program, the output should write those two files to "/home/new_files" without changes the content of the original files.

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import re
folder_path = "/home/files/d_d"
file_pattern = "/*sql"
folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)


for file in folder_contents:
    print("Checking", file)
for file in folder_contents:
    read_file = open(file, 'rt',encoding='latin-1').read()
    #words=read_file.split()
    with open(read_file,"w") as output:
        output.write(re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', f, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

I receive an error of File name too long:"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLe" and also I am not too sure where I would put my output path (/home/files/new_dd)in my code.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Simply run throught my directory and filter it by adding the regex element and then save the file.

Comment: What is there to not understand?

Comment: could you an example of `folder_contents`, perhaps a list with the contents of that variable

Answer (score 0):

With `read_file = open(file, 'rt',encoding='latin-1').read()` the whole content of the file was being used as the file descriptor. The code provided here iterate over the files names found with glob.glob pattern open to read, process data, and open to write (assuming that a folder `newfile_sqls` already exist,
if not, an error would rise `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`).

```
import glob
import os
import re

folder_path = "original_sqls"
#original_sqls\file1.sql, original_sqls\file2.sql, original_sqls\file3.sql
file_pattern = "*sql"
# new/modified files folder
output_path = "newfile_sqls"

folder_contents = glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path,file_pattern))

# iterate over file names
for file_ in [os.path.basename(f) for f in folder_contents]:

    # open to read
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path,file_), "r") as inputf:
        read_file = inputf.read()

    # use variable 'read_file' here
    tmp = re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', read_file, flags=re.DOTALL)

    # open to write to (previouly created) new folder
    with open(os.path.join(output_path,file_), "w") as output:
        output.writelines(tmp)
```